# Submit button in Joomla module not work

Tags: javascript, php, joomla3.0

Please advise how to solve Joomla! issue.
In the PHP file outside Joomla! **Submit** button works perfect and starts **POST** method to send data to the DB.
When I have created Joomla! module with exactly the same code inside, covered with {source}{/source} tags and after fill the form, I get following error message in console:

```js
< div class = "g-block size-100" >
  <div id = "custom-8642-particle"
class = "g-content g-particle" > < h2 class = "g-title" > We are sorry! < /h2> <
  p > Gantry 5 provides a custom error page
for you to configure with either positions, particles or a combination of both, as well as styling. < /p> <
  /div>
```

PHP file code worked outside of Joomla! and provided this error is here:

```html
<?php
require_once ("pg_conn.php");
if (isset ( $_POST ['submit'] )) {
    $elem = $_POST;
    foreach ( $elem as $key => $value ){
    }
    unset ( $elem ['submit'] );
    $res = pg_insert ( $dbconn, 'test.tb_54646', $elem );
    if ($res) {
        echo "Record completed";
    } else {
        echo "NOT completed";
    }
}
?>

  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>

    <script>
      function sendForm(form) {
        form.submit();
      }
    </script>

  </head>

  <body>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <form method="post" action="area.php">

          <tr>
            <td><label for="street">Street:</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="street" onchange="sendForm(this.form)"></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td><label for="building_no">Building No:</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="bld_no"></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td><label for="ID Sector">ID Sector:</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="id_sector"></td>
          </tr>
          ------------------
          <tr>
            <td><input type="reset" name="reset" value="Clear It"></td>
            <td><input type="submit" onClick="return nodata(this.form)" name="submit" value="Submit"> </td>
          </tr>
        </form>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>

  </html>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

It was my mistake, I didn't remove `action="area.php"` from the inserted into Joomla module code, now everything work nice after changes, instead of:

```js
< form method = "post" action = "area.php" >
```

working code:

```js
<form method ="post">
```